# How to read .lbl file

Tags: c#, file-handling

I want to read my `.lbl` file and store its data into a database column.
So, whenever the user wants to modify it, they may create a new `.lbl` file from the Database.

I have converted my `.lbl` data into Binary by using the snippet shown below:

```
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\Work\\PNS\\TEST.lbl");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (byte b in fileBytes)
{
    sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
    string bindata = sb.ToString();  // store this variable value in DataBase Column
}

File.WriteAllText("D:\\Work\\PNS\\TESTnew.lbl", sb.ToString());
```

But, When I Open a new file I get Error like this

> Unable to open label, the file or folder is not accessible, does not exist, or is already opened by another user. Try Opening the label with 'read-only' flag set!

Kindly Help me to figure out this problem

Comment: Check for permissions related issues or if the file is actually open in some other application. I hope you are not running this code on a web-server, am I right?

Comment: Are you talking about the .lbl file of a MS Access file? That is automatically created, every time the access file is opened, is constantly in read only mode and is destroyed when the access file is closed. Why do you want to edit the .lbl file?

Comment: @theghostofc I am doing this coding stuff on my Laptop and its not connect with any type of server.
and already check abt permissions and all tat.

Comment: @corak no its Not.. It is Printing Designing file, in that file we store Our Barcode Sticker image and value which are then print and stick on BOX.
Some time my client want to modify tat file and want to change in value like expirary date, prise, batch no etc

Comment: Okay, so have you looked at the probable causes the exception suggested? Is the file accessible? Does it exist? Is it opened by another user? As far as I can tell, `ReadAllBytes()` doesn't have the ability to specify opening a file in read only mode. You might need to use [File.OpenRead()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.file.openread.aspx) or some other method where you can specify that.

Comment: D'oh! And sorry about access... that's a .ldf not a .lbl. Wow, and it has only been a few years... ^_^;